# How to display search results on another page using PHP mySQL and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have search form on my `index.php` page. What I want to do, when i click on search i want to display results on another page called `search_result.php`. I am using jQuery for search form with validation for for two fields i.e `gender` and `age`. I am new to jQuery. Please help. Thank you.

My `index.php` page is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#search_form").submit(function(e)
        {
            var formObj = $(this);
            var formURL = formObj.attr("action");

        if(window.FormData !== undefined)  
            {
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: formURL,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                            $("#multi-msg-search").html('<pre><code>'+data+'</code></pre>');
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                    {
                        $("#multi-msg-search").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
                    }           
               });
                e.preventDefault();
                e.unbind();
           }
        });


        var v_gender = 1;
        var v_age = 1;
        var v_age1 = 1;

        $("#submit-btn").click(function()
            {

                //gender
                if($("#s_gender").val() == ''){
                    $("#s_gender").css("border","2px solid red");
                    $("#s_gender_error").show();
                    v_gender = 1;
                }else{
                    $("#s_gender").css("border","2px solid green");
                    $("#s_gender_error").hide();
                    v_gender = 0;
                }

                //age
                if($("#s_age").val() == ''){
                    $("#s_age").css("border","2px solid red");
                    $("#s_age_error").show();
                    v_age = 1;
                }else{
                    $("#s_age").css("border","2px solid green");
                    $("#s_age_error").hide();
                    v_age = 0;
                }

                //age1
                if($("#s_age1").val() == ''){
                    $("#s_age1").css("border","2px solid red");
                    $("#s_age1_error").show();
                    v_age1 = 1;
                }else{
                    $("#s_age1").css("border","2px solid green");
                    $("#s_age1_error").hide();
                    v_age1 = 0;
                }

            if(v_gender == 0 && v_age == 0 && v_age1 == 0 ){

            //sending form from here
            $("#search_form").submit();

            } //my code ends here

        });

        });

    </script>

<!-- ============ Home quick search form starts ===================== --> 
  <div class="profile_search">
    <div class="container wrap_1">
      <form action="search_result.php" method="GET" id="search_form" name="search_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="search_top">
         <div class="inline-block">
          <label class="gender_1">I am looking for :</label>
            <div class="age_box1" style="max-width: 100%; display: inline-block;" >
                <select id="s_gender" name="s_gender">
                    <option value="">* Select Gender</option>
                    <?php
                        $get_gender = "SELECT * FROM genders";
                        $run_gender = mysqli_query($con, $get_gender);
                            while ($row_gender = mysqli_fetch_array($run_gender)){
                                $gen_id = $row_gender['gender_id'];
                                $gen_title = $row_gender['gender_title'];
                                    echo "<option value='$gen_title' class='$gen_title'>$gen_title</option>";
                            } 
                    ?>
                </select>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-block">
          <label class="gender_1">Religion :</label>
            <div class="age_box1" style="max-width: 100%; display: inline-block;" >
                <select id="s_religion" name="s_religion">
                    <option value="">Doesn't Matter</option>
                    <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
                    <option value="Sikh">Sikh</option>
                    <option value="Chritian">Chritian</option>
                    <option value="Budhist">Budhist</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
               </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-block">
          <label class="gender_1">Occupation :</label>
            <div class="age_box1" style="max-width: 100%; display: inline-block;" >
                <select id="s_occupation" name="s_occupation">
                    <option value="">Doesn't Matter</option>
                    <?php
                        $get_occup = "SELECT * FROM occupation";
                        $run_occup = mysqli_query($con, $get_occup);
                            while ($row_occup = mysqli_fetch_array($run_occup)){
                                $occ_id = $row_occup['occ_id'];
                                $occ_title = $row_occup['occ_name'];
                                    echo "<option value='$occ_title' class='$occ_title'>$occ_title</option>";
                            } 
                    ?>
               </select>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="inline-block">
       <div class="age_box2" style="max-width: 220px;">
        <label class="gender_1">Age :</label>
        <input class="transparent" placeholder="From:" style="width: 34%;" type="text" value="" id="s_age" name="s_age">&nbsp;-&nbsp;<input class="transparent" placeholder="To:" style="width: 34%;" type="text" value="" id="s_age1" name="s_age1">
       </div>
     </div>
       <div class="inline-block">
          <label class="gender_1">Qualification :</label>
            <div class="age_box1" style="max-width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <select id="s_qualification" name="s_qualification">
                    <option value="">Doesn't Matter</option>
                    <?php
                        $get_educ = "SELECT * FROM education";
                        $run_educ = mysqli_query($con, $get_educ);
                            while ($row_ed = mysqli_fetch_array($run_educ)){
                                $educ_id = $row_ed['edu_id'];
                                $educ_title = $row_ed['edu_name'];
                                    echo "<option value='$educ_title' class='$educ_title'>$educ_title</option>";
                            } 
                    ?>
                </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="submit inline-block">
           <input id="submit-btn" class="hvr-wobble-vertical" type="submit" name="home_quick_search" value="Find Matches">
        </div>



     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- ============ Home quick search form ends ===================== -->
```

search_result.php file is;

```
<div class="col-md-9 profile_left">
     <div class="paid_people">
       <h1>Profiles You Searched</h1>
       <div class="row_1">

       <?php 
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
            require_once("includes/config.php");
            global $con;

            if(isset($_GET['home_quick_search'])){

                $search_gender = $_GET['s_gender']; 
                $search_relegion = $_GET['s_religion']; 
                $search_occupation = $_GET['s_occupation']; 
                $search_age = $_GET['s_age']; 
                $search_age1 = $_GET['s_age1']; 
                $search_qualification = $_GET['s_qualification']; 

                $get_user = "SELECT * FROM profile_details WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob) BETWEEN '%$search_age%' AND '%$search_age1%' OR gender LIKE '%$search_gender%' OR main_caste LIKE '%$search_relegion%' OR education_type like '%$search_qualification%' OR occupation like '%$search_occupation%'";

                $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user);

                while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user)){

                    $u_id = $row_user['user_id'];
                    $u_pid = $row_user['profile_id'];
                    $u_fname = $row_user['first_name'];
                    $u_relegion = $row_user['main_caste'];
                    $u_city = $row_user['city'];
                    $u_image = $row_user['photo'];
                    $u_dob = $row_user['dob'];


                 echo'
                      <div class="col-sm-6 paid_people-left">
                        <ul class="profile_item">
                          <a href="view_profile.php?userdetail_id=$u_id">
                           <li class="profile_item-img">
                              <img src="users-photo/resized_$u_image" class="img-responsive" alt="$u_fname"/>
                           </li>
                           <li class="profile_item-desc">
                              <h4>Profile ID: $u_pid</h4>
                              <p>Age: $u_dob Yrs, $u_relegion</p>
                              <h5>View Full Profile</h5>
                           </li>
                           <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                          </a>
                         </ul>
                       </div>
                       <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    '; 
                }
            }       
        ?>
       </div>    
  </div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
Create a php script to receive http requests and fetch data from the database
Create a php script called api.php on your server
Copy and paste the example below and save it
```

**Create a client script to fetch data from the API script using JQuery AJAX**

**Create a html script called client.php in the same directory with the following content in it**

**Create db dataset that can be fetched by jquery**

```
  <h2> Client example </h2>
  <h3>Output: </h3>
  <div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>

  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(function () 
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var id = data[0];              //get id
        var vname = data[1];           //get name


                    $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); //Set output element html
        //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome 
        // http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
      } 
    });
  });
```

Test code bed
Goto **client.php** in your browser, after setup and testing you should see the following

id: 1 name: power

@ref: https://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107

Comment: ...thank you i have tried as you said, but `client.php ` is not fetching data from table

Comment: @shekharjadhav it's because you're haven't successfully connected to the mysql database. Check your host, username and database creds before you try to data. Just in-case if you try to use the same resource to connect to the database, you need to make sure you can successfully connect to the server again.